# Why am I getting the wrong output?

Tags: java, eclipse

I wrote this program to exchange first and last characters in a string.

I created two classes (abc and BackFront). There are no errors in Eclipse but I do not get any output. When I click *run* I get output of some other class. What am I doing wrong?

**Class abc with main:**

```
package puneeth;
import java.lang.*;

public class abc {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        BackFront object1 = new BackFront();
        String str = "chocolate";
        object1.frontBack(str);
    }
}
```

**Class BackFront:**

```
package puneeth;
import java.lang.*;
public class BackFront {
    public String frontBack(String str) {
        String mid = str.substring(1,str.length());
        String first = str.substring(0,3);
        String last = str.substring(str.length());
        return last + mid + first;
    }
}
```

Comment: As written, it's not supposed to *output* anything.

Comment: `import java.lang.*;` is implicitly added by compiler. You don't need to write that.

Answer (score 0):

The string is changed, but you never physically print it for there to be output. You could do `System.out.println(object1.frontBack(str);` to get output from the output console.

Comment: As you said i did add the System.out.println(object1.frontBack(str) line.But still not getting any output

Answer (score 0):

What type of output are you expecting.
If you are expecting something in the output window you need this:

```
System.out.println( "My String" );
```

Answer (score 0):

That's strange ,make sure you are running the correct file .

Answer (score 0):

**Class BackFront:**

```
package puneeth;

public class BackFront {
    public void frontBack(String str) {
        String result;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
        char first = sb.charAt(0);
        sb.setCharAt(0, sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1));
        sb.setCharAt(sb.length() - 1, first);
        result = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

**Class abc with main method:**

```
package puneeth;

public class abc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BackFront object1 = new BackFront();
        String str = "chocolate";
        object1.frontBack(str);
    }

}

// Result:
//        ehocolatc
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code will make you laugh.

First of all, you need to print the returned string. Do this:

```
String res=object1.frontBack(str);
System.out.println(res);
```

Secondly, you need to make your main as STATIC. Do this:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
//your code
}
```

This will solve your problem. Hope this helps :)